# Reducing logging output from Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a feeling this is a dumb question I should have been able to find out the answer to myself, but my searches have turned up nothing, so here I am asking the question.

I'm using Fluent NHibernate for my project and all is good. Except that Fluent spams the log savagely with all of its mapping info. I'm relatively new to NHibernate and Fluent, but I'm pretty sure it's Fluent logging, not NHibernate logging.

An example of what we're seeing is this:

> id
>   property
>   property
>   property
>   many-to-one
>   bag

How can I switch this logging off? I'm guessing that all I need to do is just change a logging level but I haven't been able to find any info on what the change should be. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version are you using? Fluent NHibernate does not have any logging configuration (no logging to speak of at all, really). For a long time there was a `Console.WriteLine()` call or two but I think they've all been removed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The version we're using is 0.1.0.521. I can see there are newer builds on the site, I might give them a try.

Do you know if this output is Fluent's or NHibernate's?

Comment: It's definitely Fluent's. I found the commit from James that fixed the problem (r533: "Removed that really annoying Console.WriteLine from the mapping sorter"). We've been getting complaints about it forever, you're not the first. :)

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I'll get onto the latest version.